# How can I read a "ctrl+q" input from user using opencv and Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using:-

```
key=cv2.waitKey(1) #& 0xFF 
    if key== ord('q'):
        ....................
```

but I need the input from user to be ctrl+q

Thanks

Comment: openCV has a very limited user-interface (more for testing than for real application code). Maybe it is not possible.

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is encoded as `17` in [ASCII control key table](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm). Below is a sample code.

```
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == 17:        # Ctrl+Q or ^Q
    break
```

Comment: @WalidAhmed Have you tried my answer above? It has tested and is able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@WalidAhmed, `Ctrl`+`Anykey` interprets as single key if you use `cv::waitKeyEx()`. In example,

```cpp
std::cout << cv::waitKey() << std::endl;
std::cout << cv::waitKey() << std::endl;
```

Gives `227, 113` (`Ctrl` code, `q` code) both in combo and if they pressed separately. But

```cpp
std::cout << cv::waitKeyEx() << std::endl;
std::cout << cv::waitKeyEx() << std::endl;
```

produces `65507, 113` when keys pressed separately and `65507, 262257` in case of combination.

Sorry for C++ code, I hope you can simply reproduce it in Python. And please note that this approach is sensitive to language layout of your keyboard (i.e. mine is English-Russian and `Q` key has `Й` character in russian layout that gives `263882` code of `Ctrl` + `Й` combination). Also  I've tested it in Ubuntu. So codes might be different for the different operation systems.